# Netplan adding unwanted default route

Tags: 18.04, netplan

I am having one Ubuntu 18.04 server with 2 NIC card. One is for Public network & another is for Private. Both have been assigned static IP Address via Netplan.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd

  ethernets:
    enp26s0f1:
      dhcp4: false 
      dhcp6: false
      
    enp26s0f0:
      dhcp4: false 
      dhcp6: false
      addresses: [51.51.51.85/24]
      gateway4: 51.51.51.254
      nameservers:
       addresses: [51.51.33.99, 8.8.8.8]

  bridges:
    cloudbr0:
      interfaces: [enp26s0f1]
      addresses: [192.168.1.1/24]
      routes:
        - to: 192.168.1.0/24
          via: 192.168.1.1
      mtu: 1500
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.1, 51.51.33.99, 8.8.8.8]
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp4-overrides:
          use-routes: false
      dhcp6: false
```

It is adding Default Route like below -

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev cloudbr0 proto static
default via 51.51.51.85 dev enp26s0f1 proto static
```

I want single Default Route with 51.51.51.85. Even I tried to write down a shell script to delete the default route, but still it is not working. After few minutes, it is automatically adding 1st Default Route and stopping all connections.

How to avoid this? Am I doing something wrong? What changes do I need to made to fix the issue?

Comment: You're assigning a static IP of 192.168.1.1 to your bridge, and that's the address of the gateway. "dhcpX: false" is unnecessary as that's the default. Add "optional: true" to both ethernet interfaces.